# How to add a .dylib file in an Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Is it the same process as adding a .jar file?

Answer (score 0):

No, You need to load this .dylib in your method.
        System.load(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/opencvlibs/libopencv_java310.dylib");
Assuming libopencv_java310.dylib already added project directory.

or 
you this can be kept some path i.e /opt. Place below code in your method
System.load("/opt/opencvlibs/libopencv_java310.dylib");